# Why use logical operators when bitwise operators do the same?

Tags: javascript, operators, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Consider this condition:

```
(true & true & false & false & true) == true //returns: false
```

As you can see, the bitwise AND behavior is exactly like logical AND's:

```
(true && true && false && false && true) == true //returns: false
```

I'm wondering *why* I should use logical operations when the bitwise operations do the same as the logical ones.

*Note*: Please don't answer that's because of performance issue because it's pretty much faster in Mozilla Firefox, see this jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/bitwise-logical-and

Comment: in the second example, I think if the first value was false, the rest of the values are not evaluated, because the statement can`t be true.

Comment: Your performance test is flawed. You only test with `true` and `false` value. The performance problem will kick in when you replace with real function.

Comment: If memory serves, `&` keeps evaluating all the options while `&&` stops at the first `false`, thus not evaluating the other conditions.

Comment: Your first snippet remains valid if you replace `&` with `+` or `*`. That doesn't mean `+` or `*` _always_ do the same as the boolean `&&`.

Comment: Bitwise operations on one bit are a bit too much ;)

Comment: Do the same? How come? Even for numbers they do something different. `2 && 1` is `1`, `2 & 1` is `0`. Not constructive.

Comment: @SalmanA For boolean conditions it's correct, but I agree for your test cases.

Comment: I removed my comment because I modified the jsperf example to contain only the relevant stuff, for further information check the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most common use of short-circuit evaluations using logical operators isn't performance but avoiding errors. See this :

```
if (a && a.length)
```

You can't simply use `&` here.

Note that using `&` instead of `&&` can't be done when you don't deal with booleans. For example `&` on `2` (`01` in binary) and `4` (`10` in binary) is `0`.

Note also that, apart in `if` tests, `&&` (just like `||`) is also used because [it returns one of the operands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) :

```
"a" & "b" => 0
"a" && "b" => "b"
```

More generally, using `&` in place of `&&` is often possible. Just like omitting most `;` in your javascript code. But it will force you to think more than necessary (or will bring you weird bugs from time to time).

Comment: [**Lazy evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) usually has a broader/different meaning than [**short-circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @phant0m short-circuit is more precise here, yes. Updated.

Answer (score 13):

> bitwise operations behavior the same?

No, it's not. Bitwise operators work on integer numbers, while the logical operators have stronlgy different semantics. Only when using pure booleans, the result may be similar.

- [Bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators): Evalutate both operands, convert to 32-bit integer, operate on them, and return the number.
- [Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators): Evaluate the first operand, if it is truthy/falsy then evalutate and return second operand else return the first result. This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

You already can see this difference in the type of the result:

```
(true & true & false & false & true) === 0
(true && true && false && false && true) === false
```

Answer (score 9):

No they don't do the same. The differences are:

1. Whether the operand types are converted
2. Whether both operands are evaluated
3. The return value

```js
// sample functions 
function a() { console.log("a()"); return false; }
function b() { console.log("b()"); return true; }
```

### && (Logical AND)

1. Checks the truthiness of operands
2. Uses short-circuiting and may not evaluate the second operand
3. Returns the last evaluated operand without type conversion

```js
a() && b();
// LOG: "a()"
// RET: false
```

### & (Bitwise AND)

1. Temporarily converts the operands to their 32bit integer representation (if necessary)
2. Evaluates both operands
3. Returns a number

```js
a() & b();
// LOG: "a()"
// LOG: "b()"
// RET: 0
```

Comment: You probably meant "bitwise AND" instead of boolean.

Answer (score 4):

Almost everything is already said, but just for completeness' sake I want to take a look at the performance aspect (which you said doesn't matter, but it very well might):

JavaScript has a lot of difficult-to-remember rules on how to evaluate expressions. This includes a lot of type casting (implicit type coercion) when it comes to more complex comparisons. Arrays and Objects need to be converted by calling their `toString()` methods and are then cast to numbers. This results in a *huge* performance hit.

The logical operator `&&` is short-circuiting. This means as soon as it encounters a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, the evaluation stops and `false` is returned. The bitwise operator will always evaluate the entire statement.

Consider the following (yes, quite extreme) short circuit example when very expensive operations (casting an array and an object) are involved: ( performance according to https://jsbench.me in Chromium 90)

```
// logical operator
( false && {} && [] ) == true
//  /\ short circuits here
// performance: 805M ops/sec  

// bitwise operator
( false  & {}  & [] ) == true // evaluates the entire statement
// performance: 3.7M ops/sec
```

You can see that the performance differs by a factor of 100!

Comment: +1 Nice, but the benchmark doesn't say that performance matters. In this case, performance is mostly a red herring since the semantics are completely different.

Comment: The semantic topic hast been covered by the other answers, I just wanted to point out the performance issue caused by type coercion.

Comment: Your answer doesn't say which way is faster, and it doesn't say which operators your statements apply to. "Arrays and Objects need to be converted by calling their toString() methods and are then cast to numbers" for logical or bitwise operators? This answer makes weird assumptions about the reader just knowing what you're implying and is therefore incomplete. Also the link is broken.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I assume he means both have to be convert to a string and then to a number. Wouldn't make sense to give an example of short circuit if one of them wasn't affected as then you would have no idea which one is faster. I'm pretty sure he means logical is faster in this case.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Even though you pulled a nice necro (this thread is 8 years old ;-)), I edited my answer for clarity. I hope it is clearer now what I was trying to say?

Comment: @Christoph - Well done! Thank you for humoring me

Comment: @KyleDelaney He meant: the type conversions to integers and the lack of short-circuit mechanics in bitwise operations make them slower than logical ones. **Did _you_ understand now?**

Answer (score 3):

Because using `&&` or `&` convey different intents.

The first says you're testing [**truthiness**](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).

The second means your conjuring up some bit magic. In real code, you will be looking at `variable1 & variable2`. It will *not* be clear that you're in fact intending to test for truth (***not*** truthiness). The reader of the code will probably be confused because it's not obvious why `&` was used.

Furthermore, the semantics are *completely* different when taking into account other values than bools and function calls, as pointed out by numerous other posts.

Comment: You're right - they have adopted "truthy and falsy" (much to my personal, irrelevant chagrin ;-) ), perhaps you should link to an explanation (e.g. http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).  I'll remove my original comments.

Comment: @MadKeithV Good idea, done. I'll remove my earlier comments as well, then.

Answer (score 2):

1. Boolean allows short-circuiting, which can be a performance boost or safety check.
2. Non-boolean values used in the conditional. For example, `if ( 1 & 2 )` will return false, whereas `if ( 1 && 2 )` will return true.

Comment: I think you didn't understand bitwise and ... try `(2&3)?"true":"false"`

Comment: @Christoph Excuse me? `(2&3)` will be true because it's `0010 & 0011` which is `0010`. `(1&2)`, on the other hand, is `0001 & 0010` which is `0000`. My point was that you may get unexpected results using non-boolean values if you use the bitwise &.

Comment: Okay, I revoke my statement, however the sentence `Non-boolean values used in the conditional if will return false` implied this is true for all cases, which is not. Maybe you want to rephrase it so it's more clear what you mean.

Comment: @Christoph I think you missed the period after "conditional," but point taken. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't short-circuit bitwise operators. Also the bitwise operators can do much more, not just compute a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge difference: logical operations are short circuited. It means that (true && true && false ) is the last thing to be executed. This allows powerful constructs, such as abstract factory model using `var myFunc = mozilla.func || opera.sameFunc || webkit.evenOneMoreVariationOfTheSameConcept;`

All subexpressions of bitwise operations have to be fully evaluated -- and btw. one only rarely needs to evaluate constant bitwise or logical expressions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First condition have to convert first and sum bits then. But second will check logical and return value.

So First one will be slower than second one.

Run This Test: http://jsperf.com/bitwise-logical

on Chrome & IE Bitwise is slower 
but on  FireFox logical is slower

Comment: For boolean composition, it's not true that the first one will be slower. `&&` adds branching, which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators (& and |) converts the two operands to 32 bit "integers" and return the bit operation as a result. The conversion of an operand is 0 if it is not numeric.

The logical operators (&& and ||) are not logical at all, but rather are selectors of one of the operands or 0.

- The logical && returns the first operand if both exist, otherwise 0
- The logical || returns the first existing operand, otherwise 0
- An operand exists if not: undefined, null, false, or 0

Answer (score -1):

```
var bit1 = (((true & true) & (false & false)) & true), // return 0;
    bit2 = (((true && true) && (false && false)) && true); // return flase

alert(bit1 + ' is not ' + bit2);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you, exactly `0` is equal to `false` as @Christoph mentioned before.